# How do i fix the error bad URI(is not URI?): nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, uri, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activestorage

Running

```
Rails 6.0.2.1
Ruby 2.6.5
```

I'm implementing photo upload using ActiveStorage and DropZoneJS but at this point, it throws an error on this particular page `/users/2`.

Better errors shows this

```
URI::InvalidURIError at /users/2
bad URI(is not URI?): nil
```

car model

```
 def cover_photo(size_x, size_y)
        if self.photos.length > 0
          self.photos[0].variant(resize_to_limit: [size_x, size_y]).processed.service_url
        else
          "blank.jpg"
        end
      end
    end
```

My log file

```
Started GET "/users/2" for ::1 at 2020-05-08 11:39:09 +0000
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:3:in `show'
  Rendering users/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  [1m[36mCar Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "cars".* FROM "cars" WHERE "cars"."user_id" = ?[0m  [["user_id", 2]]
  ↳ app/views/users/show.html.erb:29
  [1m[36mActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = ?[0m  [["record_id", 1], ["record_type", "Car"], ["name", "photos"]]
  ↳ app/models/car.rb:14:in `cover_photo'
  [1m[36mActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 26], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/models/car.rb:15:in `cover_photo'
[36m  Disk Storage (0.0ms) [0m[34mChecked if file exists at key: variants/4u0kx27vmugn57zwn96o2t27mr71/36e628c6ec62cc8383a3ee5c0c8433e912780efead13846813a9f63693dd17eb (yes)[0m
[36m  Disk Storage (0.5ms) [0m[34mGenerated URL for file at key: variants/4u0kx27vmugn57zwn96o2t27mr71/36e628c6ec62cc8383a3ee5c0c8433e912780efead13846813a9f63693dd17eb ()[0m
  Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 18.4ms | Allocations: 4342)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 21ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms | Allocations: 5357)



URI::InvalidURIError - bad URI(is not URI?): nil:
  app/models/car.rb:15:in `cover_photo'
  app/views/users/show.html.erb:36
  app/views/users/show.html.erb:32

Started POST "/__better_errors/f90fad0cb966afba/variables" for ::1 at 2020-05-08 11:39:09 +0000
```

How do i fix this? And what is wrong with `cover_photo`?

Comment: Wheres the route for the url? should be something like: `get 'users/:id', to: 'controller#action'`

Comment: @tblev Just added the route you suggested but still doesn't work.

Comment: Your route is working, I was meaning where it was at, like what was the code you had.  But you're getting `Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}`. So it works, the problem seems to be in:`app/models/car.rb:15:in cover_photo'`. What is going on in that file on that line?

Comment: I assume it's `self.photos[0].variant(resize_to_limit: [size_x, size_y]).processed.service_url
` Are you sure you're getting the file?  It might not be able to read the uri because the file doesnt exist

Comment: @tblev I'm new to RoR. I'm also wondering what could possibly be the issue with that file. It's been two days now and i can't figure out why `app/models/car.rb:15:in cover_photo'` is acting this way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213424/discussion-between-maxxx-and-tblev).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your setup, I had fixed this issue by defining   `ActiveStorage::Current.host = "http://localhost:3000"` right before the use of `variant`

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/40855

Answer (score 1):

Okay, i removed `.service_url` from

`self.photos[0].variant(resize_to_limit: [size_x, size_y]).processed.service_url`

So it became

`self.photos[0].variant(resize_to_limit: [size_x, size_y]).processed`

And now the error is gone and the page loads perfectly. Not sure why

> Btw, can anyone explain?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem in the rails console, the solution was run this once:

```
ActiveStorage::Current.host = 'http://localhost:3000'
```

I got this information from [@Jan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66659542/5783745)'s answer, and from [here](https://medium.com/hungryhub-tech/fix-rails-activestorage-uri-invaliderror-e8a99fb8abc4).